# Update related opportunity records using recurring donations to find it's siblings

Tags: triggers, apex-code, apex

I'm coding within the following parameters:

- Recurring Donations and Opportunities are related via Lookup (not
  Master-Detail).
- Recurring Donations can have multiple opportunities
  related to it.
- Opportunities can only be related to one Recurring
  Donation.
- There is no lookup field on recurring donation to any of
  the linked opportunities.
- There IS a lookup field on the opportunity
  linking to the Recurring Donation.
- The first Opportunity is populated
  with the most up to date Credit Card information.
- This information
  needs to be copied onto the next opportunity created if the recurring
  donation record between both opportunities is the same.
- These are encrypted fields, otherwise i would use Process Builder or a Flow.

Below is what i thought would work, but i receive the error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(String) from the type List<Opportunity> at line 27 column 17
```

```html
trigger putCConRD on Opportunity (after update){

List<Opportunity> oppRecords = new List<Opportunity>();
//List<npe03__Recurring_Donation__c> rdRecords = new List<npe03__Recurring_Donation__c>();
Set<ID> associatedRDids = new Set<ID>();

List<Opportunity> oppToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

//For every new version of an opportunity record, add their related recurring donation to the associated Rds list. 
for(Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new){
    associatedRDids.add(Opp.npe03__Recurring_Donation__c);
    }

oppRecords = [Select Id, ChargentSFA__Card_Month__c, ChargentSFA__Card_Year__c, ChargentSFA__Card_Number__c, ChargentSFA__Card_Security__c from Opportunity where Id in :associatedRDids];
//now we should have a list of opportunity records that are associated with the recurring donations. 

//now to find the most recent close won opportunity related to that recurring donation
List<Opportunity> mostRecent = new List<Opportunity>([Select Id, ChargentSFA__Card_Month__c, ChargentSFA__Card_Year__c, ChargentSFA__Card_Number__c, ChargentSFA__Card_Security__c from Opportunity order by createdDate desc limit 1]);

for(Opportunity Opp2: oppRecords){

    Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Month__c = mostRecent[0].ChargentSFA__Card_Month__c;   
    Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Year__c = mostRecent[0].ChargentSFA__Card_Year__c;
    Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Number__c = mostRecent[0].ChargentSFA__Card_Number__c;
    Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Security__c = mostRecent[0].ChargentSFA__Card_Security__c;

    oppToUpdate.add(Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Month__c);
    oppToUpdate.add(Opp2.Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Year__c);
    oppToUpdate.add(Opp2.Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Number__c);
    oppToUpdate.add(Opp2.Opp2.ChargentSFA__Card_Security__c);
}

update OpptoUpdate;

}
```

Can someone please help me figure out where i am going wrong? Even if not code, some design guidance is appreciated. Trying to expand my apex understanding beyond basic triggers.